# How would find the OS version of the user and state it to them with a popup window?

Tags: powershell

I need to tell the user his OS version (Windows 10 Home, Windows 7 Home, etc.). I use this code:

```
$WIN7H = "Microsoft Windows 7 Home"
$WIN7U = "Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate"
$WIN7P = "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional"
$WIN7E = "Microsoft Windows 7 Enterpise"
$WIN10H = "Microsoft Windows 10 Home"

If ((Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -eg $WIN10H) {

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("This is Windows 10 Home",0,"Windows 10",0)

}else if ((Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -eg $WIN7H) {

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("This is Windows 7 Home",0,"Windows 7",0)

 }
```

to find and state the user's OS version, but I get the following error in powershell:

```
At line:7 char:60
+ ...  If ((Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -eg $WIN10H 
...
+                                                               ~~~
Unexpected token '-eg' in expression or statement.
At line:7 char:64
+ ...  ((Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -eg $WIN10H) {
+                                                                ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '$WIN10H' in expression or statement.
At line:7 char:64
+ ...  ((Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -eg $WIN10H) {
+                                                                ~~~~~~~
Missing closing ')' after expression in 'If' statement.
At line:7 char:71
+ ...  ((Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -eg $WIN10H) {
+                                                                       ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:12 char:2
+ }else if ((Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -eg $W ...
+  ~~~~
Unexpected token 'else' in expression or statement.
At line:12 char:64
+ ...  if ((Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -eg $WIN7H) 
...
+                                                               ~~~
Unexpected token '-eg' in expression or statement.
At line:12 char:68
+ ... f ((Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -eg $WIN7H) {
+                                                                 ~~~~~~
Unexpected token '$WIN7H' in expression or statement.
At line:12 char:68
+ ... f ((Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -eg $WIN7H) {
+                                                                 ~~~~~~
Missing closing ')' after expression in 'if' statement.
At line:12 char:74
+ ... f ((Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -eg $WIN7H) {
+                                                                       ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], 
ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Basically, all I need is a script to be able find the user's OS version. To be more detailed, it should be something like:

```
if ("The user is running windows 10") {

    ....something here....

}else if("He is running windows 7"){

    Then show a popup that "You are running Windows 7, you need Windows 10" 
    (or something like that...)
}
```

You may be laughing at me because it is written with bad coding skills, but I am just a beginner in powershell. Sorry :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

--
MS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `-eq` [-EQ] rather than `-eg`.

But if all you need is to send a popup to user if it is not Win 10 home, this is all your script needs to do:

```
$OS = (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).caption
if ($OS -ne "Microsoft Windows 10 Home")
{
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $wshell.Popup("This is $OS. You need Windows 10 Home",0,"Windows 10 Notification",0)
}
```

Comment: It helps in remember it that `-eq` means "equals."

Comment: Well, after I wrote `$OS = (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).caption

if ($OS -eq "Microsoft Windows 10 *")
{
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $answer = $wshell.Popup("This computer is currently running $OS. Would you like to continue with the script?",0,"Windows 10 Notification",0x4)

if($answer -eq 7){exit}` to prompt to user to continue the script (and if he clicks 'no' it will terminate) the I continued on with the script (that should execute if he clicks 'yes') and I finished off with... see next comment

Comment: ...cont. I finished off with `else {

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $wshell.Popup("You need a Windows 10 operating system to run this program. You are using $OS.",0,"Alert",16)

}` but I tested it on a Windows 7 system but the prompt of "Would you like to continue with the script?" still came up. But it should only popup that message if `$OS -ne "Microsoft Windows 10 *"`, but that was a Windows 7 system. Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot use a wildcard `*` when you use `-eq`. Right now, everything will pass your condition test. Try using `-Like` with wildcards and test to make sure it behaves as expected.

Comment: So how would I do that for any version of Windows 10?

Comment: Do you think if I use a bunch of if else statments it will work the same way? For example: `else if ($OS -eq "Microsoft Windows 10 Pro")
{
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $answer = $wshell.Popup("This computer is currently running Microsoft Windows 10 Pro. Would you like to continue with the script?",0,"Windows 10 Notification",0x4)

if($answer -eq 7){exit}

}` and so on for the other versions?

Comment: Yeah it will. But if you have more than a few choices to move through, `switch` would serve you better. If you are only trying to cover all Windows 10 versions, you can use a `wildcard` inside the `if` statement like `if($OS -notlike "Microsoft Windows 10 *"){#your code}`

Comment: so i would do `if($OS -notlike "Microsoft Windows 10 *"){the code to executed on a non windows 10 platform and exit}` then here (after the closing of the `if` statment) all the code to be executed if the machine is running Windows 10. Correct?

Comment: A more cleaner way would be to use `if-else`. So your code becomes `if (Not windows 10){#non win 10 code}else{#Win 10 code}`

Comment: So in the end it will look like `if($OS -notlike "Microsoft Windows 10 *"){you are not running win10} else{$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell $answer = $wshell.Popup("This computer is currently running Microsoft Windows 10 Pro. Would you like to continue with the script?",0,"Windows 10 Notification",0x4) if($answer -eq 7){exit} }....`. Makes sense?